# How to add multiple products to line_items in Cashier/Stripe? (As array of hashes)

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to create a Stripe checkout session, but I'm having trouble with the `line_items` part. When I want to checkout 1 product, there is no problem, but when I want to checkout multiple items I get `invalid array` back from the Stripe API.

The [Stripe documentation about checkout session line_items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items) tells me `line_items` needs to be an 'array of hashes' and I believe that's where I run into the problem.

```
$items = array();

   foreach($cart as $itemInCart){
        array_push($items, array(
            'price' => $itemInCart['product']['stripeData']['price']['id'],
            'quantity' => $itemInCart['quantity'],
        ));      
    }
```

When I `dd($items)` after running the code above:

```
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "price" => "price_1LkRKDGA4B3lyBQM1AyPTB3g"
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "price" => "price_1LkRLsGA4B3lyBQMgZvay5zZ"
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
]
```

But if I'm not mistaken, Stripe expects it to be:

```
^ array:2 [▼
  [▼
    "price" => "price_1LkRKDGA4B3lyBQM1AyPTB3g"
    "quantity" => 1
  ],
  [▼
    "price" => "price_1LkRLsGA4B3lyBQMgZvay5zZ"
    "quantity" => 1
  ]
]
```

The amount of items in `$cart` may vary, so I can't 'hardcode' the list_items; it needs to be dynamic.

```
 $checkout_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' =>  $items, // <-- Here is the $items variable
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'automatic_tax' => [
                'enabled' => true,
            ],
            'shipping_options' => [
                'shipping_rate_data' => [
                    'display_name' => 'Bezorging door PostNL',
                    'type' => 'fixed_amount',
                    'delivery_estimate' => [
                        'maximum' => 5,
                        'minimum' => 2,
                    ],
                    'fixed_amount' => [
                        'amount' => 6.25,
                        'currency' => 'eur',
                    ],
                    'tax_behavior' => 'inclusive',
                ],
            ],
            'success_url' => route('checkout.success'),
            'cancel_url' => route('checkout.cancel'),
        ]);
```

Is there a way to remove the keys from the array to make it an array of hashes, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: The keys in both arrays are effectively the same.  In PHP an array will always have a key and the default way is 0 based indexes.  There seem to be ideas on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753143/stripe-api-checkout-with-multiple-items so have a read see if that helps.

Comment: Above SO link looks good. Also there is Stripe's example code, although it's not looping through array to dynamically create the variable like you are doing: https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/blob/main/server/php/public/create-checkout-session.php#L45-L48